# When is the contraction of a maximal ideal still maximal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $F$ a subfield of $k$, $A$ a reduced, finitely generated $k$-algebra, and $A_0$ a finitely generated $F$-subalgebra of $A$ for which $A = k \otimes_F A_0$.

Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$.  Then $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is a prime ideal of $A$.  Here is my very general question:

> When is $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ a maximal ideal of $A$?

Another point of view would be to use the fact that since $k$ is algebraically closed, there is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow k$ whose kernel is $\mathfrak m$.  Then $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is the kernel of the restriction of $\phi$ to $A_0$.  So equivalently the question I'm asking is when is $\phi(A_0)$ a field (necessarily a finite extension of $F$, by Zariski's lemma).

Here is a small result:

> Let $A_0 = F[X], A = k[X]$.  Let $\mathfrak m = (X - x)$ be any maximal ideal of $A$.  Then $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ if and only if $x$ is algebraic over $F$.  Otherwise, $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is zero.

Proof: If $x$ is algebraic over $F$ with minimal polynomial $\mu$, then $\mu A_0$ is a maximal ideal of $A_0$ contained in $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$, so the inclusion $\mu A_0 \subseteq \mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is an equality.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is a maximal ideal of $A_0$.  Since $A_0$ is a PID, and we know that $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is prime, this is the same as saying that $\mathfrak m \cap A_0 \neq 0$.  So there exists a polynomial $f(X) \in k[X]$ such that $(X-x)f(X) \in F[X]$.  This is a polynomial in $F[X]$ of which $x$ is a root, so $x$ is algebraic over $F$. $\blacksquare$

The next step would be to consider $A_0 = F[X_1, ... , X_n], A = k[X_1, ... , X_n]$, and $\mathfrak m = (X_1 - x_1, ... , X_n - x_n)$.  A natural thing to expect would be that $\mathfrak m \cap A$ is a maximal ideal of $A_0$ if and only if all the $x_i$ are algebraic over $F$.  I have not been successful in proving this yet, but it may follow from using induction and some facts about flat extensions of rings.  Maybe a more general result to expect would be that the height of $\mathfrak m \cap A_0$ is $$ n - \textrm{tr. deg}(F[x_1, ... , x_n]/F)$$

The final step would be to consider quotients $$A = k[X_1, ... , X_n]/I, A_0 = F[X_1, ... , X_n]/I \cap F[X_1, ... , X_n]$$ where $I$ is an ideal of $A$ which is extended from an ideal of $F[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  Up to noncanonical isomorphism, I believe such extensions $A_0 \rightarrow A$ cover all pairs $(A,A_0)$ as I described in the beginning of the question.